# How to resolve ambiguity when mocking mock<RestTemplate> getForObject?

Tags: kotlin, mockito, resttemplate

Using `com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2` for testing `restTemplate.getForObject(url, Int::class.java)`, url is type of `String!`

Trying to mock `RestTemplate::getForObject`:

```
val restTemplate = mock<RestTemplate> {
        on { getForObject(any(), any()) } doReturn ResponseEntity.ok(Object())
    }
```

But get an error:

```
Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match.
public open fun <T : Any!> getForObject(url: URI!, responseType: Class<TypeVariable(T)!>!): TypeVariable(T)! defined in org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate
public open fun <T : Any!> getForObject(url: String!, responseType: Class<TypeVariable(T)!>!, vararg uriVariables: Any!): TypeVariable(T)! defined in org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate
```

And

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
Unit
Found:
ResponseEntity<Object!>!
```

Please help, I'm new in Kotlin

Comment: Can you please add the code that you are trying to test? Thanks!

Comment: `restTemplate.getForObject(url, Int::class.java)`,  `url` is type of String!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Mockito that it should expect a `String` as a first argumet. Try the following:

```kotlin
val restTemplate = mock<RestTemplate> {
    on { getForObject(anyString(), eq(Int::class.java)) } doReturn 200
}
```

You can read more about `anyString()` in the [reference documentation](https://site.mockito.org/javadoc/current/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#anyString()).

Comment: it's a problem with `any()` here: `Not enough information to infer type variable T`

Comment: Thank you, but it's a problem with `ResponseEntity.ok(Object())`:  `Type mismatch.
Required:
Int!
Found:
ResponseEntity<Int!>!` and changing to `doReturn Int()` doesn't work due to: `Cannot access '<init>': it is private in 'Int'` error

Comment: My bad. Given that you are expecting an `Int` to be the response of your `getForObject()`call you need to return an `Int` while mocking the call. Please check my updated answer.